# Standard Override buttons not working in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, spring18

We have the override Standard Button(New) with visual force page, we used same page for Classic and LEX it was working few days ago , but after Spring 18 release in sandbox it stopped working in LEX. is it bug from Salesforce?

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing when you open it in LEX ?

Comment: it is navigating to new record page with default record type in profile (beacuse skip record type selection page check box is checked)

Comment: Hi Raj, I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a workaround or opened a case for this issue?

Comment: any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.The newoverirde  Visualforce page used to open in lightning before spring 18 release but now its redirecting to standard pagelayout instead of VFpage.